# Autocomplete on dyamically added rows Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I am not able to load autocomplete on dynamically created rows. I want to add a new row on calling function add row to the table and the dynamically created row should have auto complete functionality. I am able to add the row but auto complete is not working out.

```
function add_row(a) {
    count++;
    jQuery('#member').append('<tr id="row_' + counter + '"><td width="5%"align="center"    valign="middle" bgcolor="' + bgc + '">' + counter + '</td><td width="30%" bgcolor="' + bgc + '"><input name="parti_name[]" type="text" id="parti_name_' + counter + '" size="30" /><input type="hidden" name="cr_ac[]" id="cr_ac_' + counter + '" /></td><td width="20%" align="center" bgcolor="' + bgc + '"><input type="text" name="amount[]" id="amount_' + counter + '" class="am" onkeyup="calculateSum()" onchange="add_row()"/></td><td width="40%" align="center" bgcolor="' + bgc + '"><input name="narration[]" type="text" id="narration_' + counter + '" size="48" /></td><td width="5%" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="' + bgc + '"><img src="<?php echo base_url('images/the_delete_icon.png') ?>" width="16" height="16" /></td></tr>');
    counter++;
    jQuery("#parti_name_'+count+'").autocomplete({
        source: function (req, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('search'); ?>",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
                    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re, "i");
                    response($.grep(data, function (item) {
                        return matcher.test(item.label);
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#parti_name_' + count + '').val(ui.item.label);
            $('#cr_ac_' + count + '').val(ui.item.value);
        }

    });
}
```

I'm using this at the beginning of my page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" media="screen"></link>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @TusharGupta Be careful, your edit added spaces in a file name which would have made it invalid. I notice adding spaces around punctuation is a habit of yours. You shouldn't do it so often, it's a matter of preference, and especially don't do it when it's incorrect, as here or [there](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2597425) (where you added spaces in the middle of tokens!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there may may be error in concatenation replace following line with correct concatenation and try:

```
jQuery("#parti_name_'+count+'")
```

To

```
jQuery("#parti_name_"+count)
```

Comment: Thanks For your response, i corrected that but still auto complete is not working

Comment: please debug your code and use console.log(). to check what error occurs. so i can help you.